# Using intervals with Time.every in Elm

Tags: elm

I have a subscription that updates a value every second in Elm (0.18).  It looks like this:

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Time.every Time.second UpdateNote
```

How do I make something that updates every two seconds?  I'd like something like this:

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Time.every 2.0 Time.second UpdateNote
```

...but I'm not sure where to insert the time interval value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time values are float aliases, so you can multiply `second` by the number of seconds you desire:

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Time.every (Time.second * 2) UpdateNote
```